# Expected Value of $P(|Y_n^{(K)}| > \epsilon)$ where $Y_n^{(K)}$ is the random sum of a sequence of RV converging to 0 in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have been struggling with this for countless hours, I would appreciate a hint to get me going in the right direction (no complete answer please)

> **Problem:** Assume that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the sequence $(X_n^{(k)})_{n \geq 1}$ of real RV is such that $X_n^{(k)}\to 0$ in Probability. We define for a $\mathbb{N}$-valued RV $K$ independent of $X_n^{(k)}$ the random sum $$Y_n^{(K)} := \sum_{i=1}^K X_n^{(i)} $$
>   Show the formula $$E(P(|Y_n^{(K)}| > \epsilon ))=P (|Y_n^{(K)}| > \epsilon) $$

---

I am absolutely lost on this.

I managed to show that $Y_n^{(k)}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ converges to $0$ in Probability. I believe in this problem it is key to understand that $K$ as a $\mathbb{N}$-valued RV is independent of the sequence $(X_n^{(k)})_{n \geq 1}$, formally this means that for all Borel sets $A,B$ we have $$P(K \in A,X_n^{(k)} \in B) = P(K \in A) \cdot  P(X_n^{(k)} \in B), \ \forall k,n \in \mathbb{N}$$
And it probability makes sense here to specialize this for $A= \mathbb{N},B= \mathbb{R}$, but I have no idea how this affects the random sum $Y_n^{(K)}$, intuitively I would say that if random sum is adding up outcomes of an experiment then the sum will always  go to $K(\omega)$ no matter what the outcome of the experiment was (for example if $1$ or $0$ doesn't affect that we run at exactly $K(\omega)=50$ experiments)

Should I try to show two inequalities? Or do I need a certain property of the random sum?

Comment: The question asks to show that, if $z$ is some deterministic number then $E(z)=z$. Well, indeed. (Here, $z=P(|Y_n^{(K)}| > \epsilon) $.)

Comment: I do understand that for every number $c$ we have $E(c)=c$, but do I see it right that the only thing that makes $z=P(|Y_n^{(K)}| > \epsilon)$ deterministic is the fact that $K$ is independent of the sequence $(X_n^{(k)})_n$?

Comment: No, rather the fact that $z$ is the probability of an event.

Comment: Did you mean $$E[P(Y_n^{(K)} > \varepsilon|K)]$$ or something?

Comment: This may be helpful: [Random Sums of Random Variables](http://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/ProbabilityTheory/Lessons/Conditionals/RandomSums/randsum.shtml). I think we're supposed to have something like this: $$E[P(Y_n^{(K)} > \varepsilon|K)]$$

$$ = E[E[1_{Y_n^{(K)} > \varepsilon}|K]]$$

$$ = E[1_{Y_n^{(K)} > \varepsilon}]$$

$$ = P(Y_n^{(K)} > \varepsilon)$$